# INNER JOIN listado en Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Tengo estas 2 tablas

**Tabla Productos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla Saldos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero listar la tabla de tal manera que me muestre todo los datos de la primera tabla mas la cantidad de acuerdo al id, lo hice con esta sentencia:

```
    SELECT Articulos.id, Articulos.nombreProducto, Articulos.Precio, Saldos.Cantidad
      FROM Articulos 
INNER JOIN Saldos ON Articulos.id = Saldos.id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de hacer esto mismo pero usando EF en C# pero no me sale, llevo esto pero esta mal

```
public List<Articulos> listar(){
    var arti = new List<Articulos>();

    try{
        using (var ctx = new ModeloProductos()){
            arti = ctx.Articulos.Include("Saldos")
                                .Include("Saldos.id")
                                .Where(x => x.id == id)
                                .ToList();
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {
        throw;
    }
    return arti;
}
```

como puedo pasar ese INNER JOIN al EF?

**EDITADO
Modelo de la db Productos**

```
namespace PruebaVictorDuarte.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class ModeloProductos : DbContext
    {
        public ModeloProductos()
            : base("name=ModeloProductos")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Articulos> Articulos { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Bitacora> Bitacora { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Saldos> Saldos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Articulos>()
                .Property(e => e.nombreProducto)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Articulos>()
                .Property(e => e.Precio)
                .HasPrecision(18, 4);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Articulos>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Bitacora)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Articulos)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Articulos>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Saldos)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Articulos)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Bitacora>()
                .Property(e => e.Historial)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Articulos**

```
namespace PruebaVictorDuarte.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class Articulos
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Articulos()
        {
            Bitacora = new HashSet<Bitacora>();
            Saldos = new HashSet<Saldos>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string nombreProducto { get; set; }

        public decimal Precio { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Bitacora> Bitacora { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Saldos> Saldos { get; set; }


        /*AGREGA DATOS DEL PRODUCTO A LA TABLA
         Y RECUPERA EL ID INSERTADO*/
        public int addArticulo(string nombre, decimal pp)
        {
            int idCate=0;

            var datos = new Articulos
            {
                nombreProducto = nombre,
                Precio = pp
            };

            using (var ctx = new ModeloProductos())
            {
                ctx.Entry(datos).State = EntityState.Added;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                idCate = datos.id;
            }

            return idCate;
        }


    }


}
```

**Saldos**

```
namespace PruebaVictorDuarte.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class Saldos
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }

        public virtual Articulos Articulos { get; set; }

        /*ESTABLECE EL SALDO PRIMARIO EN CERO ("0")*/
        public void setSaldo(int sal)
        {
            int saldo = 0;

            var datos = new Saldos
            {
                id=sal,
                Cantidad = saldo
            };

            using(var ctx=new ModeloProductos()){

                ctx.Entry(datos).State = EntityState.Added;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes revisar esta pregunta tal vez te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876304/c-sharp-linq-inner-join

Comment: Si configuras bien las llaves foráneas y trabajas con Lazy Loading, Linq to Entities lo hace por vos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para consultas con joins como regresas datos mezclados de tablas no es recomendable que regreses el objeto de una entidad, si no que declares un objeto que contendrá los datos de tu consulta de varias tablas, por ejemplo:

```
public class ArticuloSaldo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NombreProducto { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

Y el query de esta forma que es más parecida a SQL y fácil de entender:

```
using(var ctx = new ModeloProductos())
{
    var query = from a in ctx.Articulos
                join s in ctx.Saldos on a.id equals s.id
                select new ArticuloSaldo { 
                    Id = a.id, 
                    NombreProducto = a.nombreProducto, 
                    Precio = a.Precio, 
                    Cantidad = s.Cantidad };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Linq to entities hace de manera automática el inner join, basándote en tu modelo, por ejemplo, en caso de usar code first, si tuvieses el siguiente modelo

```
class A
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string CampoDeEjemplo { get; set; }
    public int B_Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("B_Id")]
    public B Inner { get; set; }

}

class B
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OtroCampoEjemplo { get; set; }
}
```

Al momento de realizar una query con linq to entities, podes elegir dos métodos de carga, `LazyLoading` y `EagerLoading`, en el caso del primero, realizará los `INNER JOIN` de manera automática, en el segundo, lo harías a mano (en caso de tener muchas relaciones, te generaría una performance muy superior)

**Ejemplo LazyLoading**

```
using(var db = new TuDBContext())
{
    //Por lo general está definido por defecto de esta manera
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    var Ejemplo = db.A.Where(x =>x.Id==3).First();
    Console.WriteLine(A.Inner.OtroCampoEjemplo); //Debería dar como resultado, el contenido de B relacionado con A en la base de datos
}
```

**Ejemplo EagerLoading** (manualmente incluyo a b (`.Include("B")`)

```
using(var db = new TuDBContext())
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    var Ejemplo = db.A.Include("B").Where(x =>x.Id==3).First();
    Console.WriteLine(A.Inner.OtroCampoEjemplo); //Debería dar como resultado, el contenido de B relacionado con A en la base de datos
}
```

Espero que se entienda bien, si seguís teniendo problemas respecto a este tema, estaría bueno que edites la pregunta, agregando de manera más precisa tu modelo!

Perdón si hay algún error de sintaxis, estoy sin ide!

Saludos!

Edit: de más estaría decir, que si las relaciones del modelo no están bien configuradas, no va a funcionar!

Comment: Mas o menos pero a la vez no, soy muy nuevo en EF, y no como colocar el mismo ejemplo pero con lo que puse!! (Agrego el modelo a la pregunta)

Comment: Vi tu edición, como modelo, me refiero a las clases `Articulos` y `Sueldos` !

Comment: reeditado, agregre las clases que hacian falta